# Simplify parameters of excel formula using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a UDF that has the parameters as such:

```
=MySampleUDF(150+127.193,1000,240-30-12)
```

How can I use VBA to reduce the above to this (i.e. calculate & simplify all the parameters):

```
=MySampleUDF(277.193,1000,198)
```

I've tried to think of ways that involve Regex, but really there must be a simpler way?

Comment: Highlight the parameter and press `F9` to convert it into a value within an Excel cell.

Comment: This seems like bad design. You want the UDF to pull parameters from cells where the values used are obvious, and not do hidden calculations that hide the intent of the function. Better to do `=MySampleUDF(A2,C2,D2)` for example instead of `=MySampleUDF(277.193,1000,198)`

Comment: This converts the whole cell into value and strips out the UDF completely. I want to keep the UDF and only convert the parameters to values.

Comment: You didn't select the parameter to evaluate _before_ pressing `[F9]`.  Try again, edit the cell, highlight `150+127.193` and press `[F9]`.

Comment: This is ultimately what I need done manually in Excel VBA. Whilst I agree - it's better to have all these values in cells, I'm working with a spreadsheet that I've inherited with lots of these UDFs (we're talking sheets and sheets worth). I need to simplify all of these

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to `Evaluate` each parameter in the Formula, and turn it into a single value?

The method below is *far* from perfect; if your parameter includes a formula, then it **will** fail (e.g. `=MySampleUDF(150+127.193,999+1+PRODUCT(7+3,0),240-30-12)` will result in `=MySampleUDF(277.193,999+1+PRODUCT(10,0),198)`), but it forms an almost-decent starting point, and doesn't require any advanced understanding.  There are, undoubtedly, **many** ways to improve it, with more time.

```
Sub SimplifyParameters(Target AS Range)
    Dim aBrackets AS Variant, bClose As Boolean, aParams AS Variant
    Dim lCurrBracket AS Long, lCurrParam As Long, rCurrCell AS Range
    Dim sProcessBracket AS String, vEvaluated AS Variant
    
    For Each rCurrCell In Target.Cells 'In case you input more than 1 cell
        If Len(rCurrCell.Formula)>0 Then 'Ignore blank cells
            aBrackets = Split(rCurrCell.Formula, "(") 'Split by Function
            
            For lCurrBracket = lBound(aBrackets) to UBound(aBrackets)
                aProcessBracket = aBrackets(lCurrBracket)
                bClose = (Right(sProcessBracket,1)=")")
                If bClose Then sProcessBracket = Left(sProcessBracket, Len(sProcessBracket)-1)
                
                aParams = Split(sProcessBracket, ",") 'Split by Parameter
                For lCurrParam = lBound(aParams) to uBound(aParams)
                    vEvaluated - Evaluate(aParams(lCurrParam))
                    If Not IsError(vEvaluated) Then aParams(lCurrParam) = vEvaluated
                Next lCurrParam
                
                aBrackets(lCurrBracket) = Join(aParams, ",") & IIF(bClose, ")", "") 'Recombine Parameters
            Next lCurrBracket
            
            rCurrCell.Formula = Join(aBrackets, "(") 'Recombine Functions
        End If
    Next rCurrCell
End Sub
```

It `Split`s the Formula on "(", to separate functions

```
"=MySampleUDF(150+127.193,1000,240-30-12)"
    [0] = "=MySampleUDF"
    [1] = "150+127.193,1000,240-30-12)"
```

Then it goes through those, removes the ")", and `Split`s them on ","

```
"=MySampleUDF"
    [0] = "=MySampleUDF"

"150+127.193,1000,240-30-12"
    [0] = "150+127.193"
    [1] = "1000"
    [2] = "240-30-12"
```

Then it runs the `Evaluate` function on each of those and, if the result is not an error, substitutes it in

```
Evaluate("=MySampleUDF") = Error 2029
Evaluate("150+127.193") = 277.193
Evaluate("1000") = 1000
Evaluate("240-30-12") = 198
```

Then it `Join`s the Parameters back together, and restores any removed ")"

```
Join(Array("=MySampleUDF"), ",") & "" = "=MySampleUDF"
Join(Array(277.193, 1000, 198), ",") & ")" = "277.193,1000,198)"
```

Finally, it `Join`s the Functions back together

```
Join(Array("=MySampleUDF", "277.193,1000,198)"), "(") = "=MySampleUDF(277.193,1000,198)"
```

Comment: So this is very similar to what I came up with (Except I had a solution using Regex). But as you say, it's quite messy (three for loops deep) and subject to errors - e.g. if you have a cell reference as one of the parameters, this all falls apart. I was hoping for something a bit simpler and praying that someone would tell me this isn't the only way!

Comment: @EC99 The only way I can see to tidy it up would be to add *even more* loops, to strip out just the Numerical portions of each Parameter and combining them according to BODMAS rules.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a subroutine that takes the selected cell and parses out the arguments of the any function, then evaluates each one and re-composes the formula definition.

For example the selected cell has `=SUM(1+2+3,10)` as formula.

After calling the sub the cell has `=SUM(6,10)` as formula

```
Public Sub EvalParams()
    Dim r As Range
    
    For Each r In Selection
        
        Dim f As String
        f = r.Formula
        
        If Left(f, 1) = "=" Then
            Dim i_open  As Long
            i_open = InStr(2, f, "(")
            Dim id As String
            ' Get UDF name
            id = Mid(f, 2, i_open - 2)
            
            Dim i_close As Long
            i_close = InStr(i_open + 1, f, ")")
            
            Dim args() As String
            ' Seperate arguments by comma
            args = VBA.Split(Mid(f, i_open + 1, i_close - i_open - 1), ",")
            
            Dim i As Long
            ' Evaluate each argument separately
            For i = 0 To UBound(args)
                args(i) = CStr(Evaluate(args(i)))
            Next i
            
            ' Compose formula again
            f = "=" & id & "(" & VBA.Join(args, ",") & ")"
            
            r.Formula = f
        End If
    
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

NOTE: This will fail if you have multiple function calls in the formula, like

```
=SUM(1,2,3) + SUM(4,5)
```

Comment: Appreciate this, but same issue it seems as the other answer - it fails if you have one of the parameters referring to a cell, e.g. B53

Comment: I think I know how to fix this. Each range has a `.DependentCells` property that can be used to pull those values in. @EC99 Can you please edit the question to include an example of formula with numbers and cells for testing purpuses.

Comment: @EC99 - I tested my code with `=SUM(3,F6,2*F6)` for example and it works. So the issue with cell value must be related to something else. Note that I tested with the cells in the active sheet only.